# Storing value from data.properties as a string

Tags: java, selenium

I have a value name=Merin in my data.properties file. I want to compare this in my test with a value in the website I am testing.

For comparison, I use

```
if(m.equals("Merin"){..}
```

But I would like to make this dynamic by giving a variable b instead of "Merin" in my if statement

I tried:

```
String b = driver.get(prop.getProperty("name"));
```

But am getting error: Type mismatch cannot convert void to String

How can I sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this was my mistake,

I had to give it as

```
String b = prop.getProperty("name");
```

driver.get is to get the url.

Answer (score 2):

remove driver.get() from the following statement because return type of driver.get() is void.

```
String b = driver.get(prop.getProperty("name"));
```

Change it to following and your issue will be solved.

```
String b = prop.getProperty("name");
```